# How does Original Estimate work in Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs

If I pull up a task for a particular project there is a field called original estimate. The only place I can find the original estimate is in the Tfs_Warehouse database in the FactWorkItemHistory table under the Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_OriginalEstimate column.

Can someone clarify how this value works? The reason I ask is it changes in the FactWorkItemHistory table for the same task. There are some positive entries and negative entries. If I sum up all of the Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_OriginalEstimate values by Task and ProjectNodeSK I come up with the amount that will be show up in the TFS task UI. I'm just wondering why the value changes over entries. In fact, I also would be curious as to why there are multiple WorkItem entries for the same task. I figured (incorrectly) that the WorkItem table would be a one to one as far as the Task in the TFS UI goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's a **data warehouse**. It's showing you how the value changed over time, not just a snapshot of the current value. This enables deeper reporting on trends.

Comment: Why would the original estimate change multiple times?  There are several records and the original estimate changes 1,-1,1,-1,1.5,1.5,-1.5.  It seems to me that "original estimated" would maybe change from null to something and then remain somewhat static.

Is there somewhere I can get the current value?

Comment: It looks like I'm looking for FactCurrentWorkItem.  I'm still trying to figure out how TFS structures their data.